# Number execution of recursive function

Tags: algorithm, recursion, complexity-theory, divide-and-conquer

I have this recursive algorithm and T(n) is the number of times that P(a, b) is executed and n := b - a

```
int foo[] = ... // array of big enough size
function P(int a, int b) 
    if (a+1 < b) {
       int h = floor((a+b)/2)
       if foo[h] >= 0 then P(a, h)
       if foo[h] <= 0 then P(h, b)
    }
end function
```

how can I compute T(1), T(2), T(3) and T(4)

Comment: `h` is the midpoint between `a` and `b`. Therefore, both distances `[a, h]` and `[h, b]` have length `ceil(n/2)` (assuming `foo` is such that you always choose the bigger range).  With that knowledge, you should be able to calculate the timings.

Comment: how did u get to the conclusion that they have length ceil(n/2)

Comment: Ignoring the rounding, we could calculate `h - a = (a + b) / 2 - a = b / 2 - a / 2 = (b - a) / 2 = n / 2`. Same for the case `b - h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As each time the distance between `a` and `b` (as an input of the function) is cut half, the time complexity is `Theta(log(b-a))`.